What is the optimal sample size when determining the overlap of two subsets?
Let's say I start with a set of elements ~ 100M in size. In addition, let's say I can partition the set in a deterministic way.
Now given two arbitrary subsets, perhaps few million in size, but sometimes less, I wish to determine the overlap percentage between the two subsets. I assume I do not need to read the entire subsets to do this?
How can I determine the overlap percentage without having to process all the data? I am thinking about keeping only a partition of the subsets and processing that? Are there better ways?
